# Howto connect eclipse tasklist (Mylyn) to google code?

Tags: eclipse, google-code, mylyn

I'm using Eclipse Galileo. I want to connect the eclipse tasklist to a google code project. I need a connecter to do this. Connectors can be installed via Task Resoitory view -> add TaskRepopsitory -> Install more Connectors. But I can't see that one of the listed connectors will support google code.

I searched the web and read about the Web Templates Connector. But most information I found refer to eclipse Ganymede. There is a download on [this](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/downloads/) page. Its a zip file wich contains the Web Templates Connector. I was not able to add this site to the eclipse update sites. I downloaded the file and added it to the update sites via the "add Archive" function. But it seems eclipse is expecting a jar file there and stops the installation because the hashcodes are not equal.

How do I install the Web Templates Connector to eclipse Galileo?
Is there another connector which I can use ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In case someone else is led to this page by Google The zip file is no loner available, and I found a connector here: http://code.google.com/p/googlecode-mylyn-connector/ Steps to use it (8-13): http://code.google.com/p/nemadiy/wiki/Eclipse_Environment Thanks to the authors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to install the web templates you have two options:

1. If you have a web server at your disposal (or just install Apache o your machine) - Download the [zip file](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/tools/mylyn/update/mylyn-3.3.1-incubator.zip) you refer to and extract it into a new folder under the web server. Now use the standard eclipse plugin installation to add this address (like http://localhost/mylyn-webtemplates/) to the plugin sources and install the plugin.
2. A simpler approach - download the [zip file](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/tools/mylyn/update/mylyn-3.3.1-incubator.zip) you refer to and extract the features and plugins directories from the zip to the dropins directory under eclipse. Restart the eclipse and the plugins should be loaded.

Comment: Thanks. I solved it with the first approach. But Isn't there an simpler way to do this, like an update site or something like this?

Comment: What you have created is an update site. I didn't find one on the eclipse site - perhaps they hid it or renamed it too well...

Answer (score 4):

I just added a new Mylyn update site based on the URI of the extras. My extras showed up as:

```
Mylyn Extras - http://download.eclipse.org/tools/mylyn/update/extras
```

and the Eclipse download site refered to 3 sites were the first 2 were already listed:

```
/tools/mylyn/update/e3.4
/tools/mylyn/update/extras        
/tools/mylyn/update/incubator
```

So I added the Mylyn software site:

```
  Mylyn Incubator - http://download.eclipse.org/tools/mylyn/update/incubator
```

Worked for me, hope it will for you.